# In mongo, is it possible to have an _id that would look valid but could never exist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am making unit tests for a web application and I want to make a test case to see if my app will send back the appropriate error message when someone tries to get a mongo document that could never exist.

To give a bit more context, The web app sends back information about certain items based off the _id of that item in the mongo database. The user is able to get the _id of any item as all items are view-able to the public.

What I want to know is, is it possible to have an _id that could be queried in a database but it could never exist?

If this is possible then I could make a test case that would query the mongo db and send back the appropriate error message every time guaranteed. Right now, I'm using a mongo _id that was assigned to an item that no longer exists.

My requirement for this _id is that:

- 1) it needs to be the same length of a normal _id
- 2) it needs to be
  composed of the same characters as a _id (hexadecimal I'm assuming)
- 3) it could never actually be a real _id that mongo would assign to a
  document.

Its also worth noting, that the user could never assign a _id when they create an item. All _id assignment is being handled by mongo.

If it fits all of the above I would be happy.

They only thing I could think of is 000000000000000000000000 but I cant confirm if this can be used as an _id or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but, for some reason, mongo would never be able to assign that _id

You need to distinguish "mongodb will never generate this id" and "mongodb will never accept this id if we provide it".

For the former, your example of all-zero object id is fine. Mongodb will never generate an id like that (because of timestamp generation rule, if nothing else)

If the latter, it's impossible. A mongo object id is basically a 12-byte binary blob, with no invalid or restricted values. All values are valid.

Also note that `_id` field can take most any value: strings, numbers, object ids, objects, what-have-you. Except arrays.

Comment: Hi Sergio, Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question now. Im more concern about the latter in this case. Knowing how mongo assigns _id does help which coming up with an _id for my test case though. What im really looking for is an _id that I could use in my teat case that would always bring back my error message of "An item with this _id doesn't.". If the _id are determined by timestamps then an all zero _id should cover this.

Comment: @DavidOGrady "but it could never exist?" - again, don't confuse the two cases. This id can definitely exist (if you insert it explicitly). It's just that mongodb will not generate it by itself. Just making sure you understand the distinction.

Comment: In the web app, the user cannot assign the _id when they try to create an item so we don't have to worry about _id being insert explicitly. Thanks for the follow up.